# what is the statement for "where" condtion in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper

I want to make a trigger that will be executed for each row before delete on the table Clients, what I'm trying to do is when some one tries to delete a row :

```
DELETE FROM Clients WHERE id=5 AND name = 'test';
```

I want to print something on the screen like : 
"you deleted with the following conditions : id is 5  , name is test " 
or execute another query with same conditions ...

Any kind of help is very appreciated

**EDIT**

let's suppose the user typed the following query : `DELETE FROM Clients where name = 'test'`

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER DELETECLIENT 
BEFORE DELETE ON CLIENTS
DECLARE 
pragma autonomous_transaction;
name1 clients.name%Type; 
BEGIN
  select name into name1 from clients where  name = %I want here the name in the user query %;   
  IF name1 != null THEN 
    DELETE FROM clients WHERE name = name1;
    commit;
  END IF; 
END;
```

what I've tested :

i tried adding :old.name , and :new.name , but this doesn't work when the the row doesn't exist in my database

**PS** : i'm doing this for educational purpose only, I know the script doesn't make sense. i just wan't to know how to achieve the following task : getting the parameters typed after WHERE in the query

Comment: What has the title got to do with the question? It doesn't really make sense to 'display' a message within any PL/SQL as you can't assume the client will actually display it. Do you mean that you want to raise an exception for certain values, and do something else - 'execute a query'!? - otherwise?

Comment: PL/SQL does not "print on the screen".

Comment: @AlexPoole yes i want to do this : raise_application_error(-20050, 'bla bla ' );
i know it cancel the query but it's okey

Comment: So... I still don't understand the title, you want to know how `if ... then` works in PL/SQL? What trigger code do you have so far - please add your current version to the question.

Comment: How can the row not exist - the trigger won't fire if you try to delete something that doesn't exist? And `:new` values aren't set in an `on delete` trigger. Why are you deleting again inside the trigger, and why have you made it autonomous? I know you said it doesn't make sense - but it needs to make a bit more sense to figure out what you're really asking...

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for your interest in my problem, yes my main problem is that the trigger doesn't fire when i try to delete something that is not in my table, I'm putting my self in a scenario where if it doesn't exist on my table i should try to find it on other site and delete it : 
`SELECT name into name1 from clients@site2 where name = ... `
then if exists there 
`delete from client@site2 where name = ... `

Comment: You can't make a row-level trigger fire when there is no data; and if it's a statement-level trigger (as this is, I just noticed) then you can't refer to `:old` or `:new` as they don't have any meaning - since multiple rows might have been affected. A trigger is the wrong way to approach the problem in your last comment - as it is for most problems. You should test whether your delete made any changes, and decide whether to delete from the link based on that.

Comment: @AlexPoole so can you please tell me how to make this kind of delete on different sites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [correlation names and pseudorecords](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955) the represent, i.e. `:old` and `:new` by default, only have any meaning for row-level triggers:

> **Note:**
>   This topic applies only to triggers that fire at row level—that is, row-level simple DML triggers and compound DML triggers with row-level timing point sections.

You cannot refer to these in a statement-level trigger, and only `:old` would have any meaning in a `delete` trigger. On the other hand, statement-level triggers fire even if no data is affected, whereas a row-level trigger won't fire if, in your example, no data is deleted - because there are no matching rows in your table. (This applies for `instead of` triggers for views as well, in case you're wondering if that would be a workaround).

So basically you can't do what you're attempting - conditionally deciding whether to delete from another table instead - from a trigger. Triggers are rarely the right answer. For your 'scenario where if it doesn't exist on my table i should try to find it on other site and delete it' you can try to delete a row locally, test whether it did anything, and then decide to delete from the remote table if it didn't. In a PL/SQL block that might be as simple as:

```
create procedure delete_client(p_name clients.name%type) as
begin
  delete from clients where name = p_name;
  if sql%rowcount = 0 then
    delete from clients@site2 where name = p_name;
  end if;
end delete_client;
/
```

And rather than deleting directly from the table, you make everyone call the procedure instead. Say you start off with some data:

```
select * from clients;

        ID NAME     
---------- ----------
         1 Joe        
         2 Anna       

select * from clients@site2;

        ID NAME     
---------- ----------
         1 Joe        
         3 Max
```

Then calling the procedure for two names:

```
exec delete_client('Joe');
exec delete_client('Max');
```

... has removed local and remote records appropriately:

```
select * from clients;

        ID NAME     
---------- ----------
         2 Anna       

select * from clients@site2;

        ID NAME     
---------- ----------
         1 Joe
```

`Joe` was only deleted from the local schema despite existing in both; `Max` didn't exist locally so was deleted from the remote schema.

It doesn't have to be a procedure; if you're deleting through JDBC etc. you can test the result of an `execute()` call to see how many rows were affected, which is all `sql%rowcount` is doing really, and the application code can decide whether to do the second `delete`.

But with a procedure (probably in a package) you can grant `execute` on that, and remove `delete` privileges from the users, so they can't bypass this check and do a straight `delete from clients where ...`

---

If you *really* want some 'display' output for testing purposes:

```
create procedure delete_client(p_name clients.name%type) as
begin
  delete from clients where name = p_name;
  if sql%rowcount > 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || sql%rowcount
      || ' rows from local schema for "' || p_name || '"');
  else
    delete from clients@site2 where name = p_name;
    if sql%rowcount > 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || sql%rowcount
        || ' rows from remote schema for "' || p_name || '"');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('No rows deleted on local or remote schema for "'
        || p_name || '"');
    end if;
  end if;
end delete_client;
/

set serveroutput on
exec delete_client('Joe');

anonymous block completed
Deleted 1 rows from local schema for "Joe"

exec delete_client('Max');

anonymous block completed
Deleted 1 rows from remote schema for "Max"

exec delete_client('Fred');

anonymous block completed
No rows deleted on local or remote schema for "Fred"
```

But you shouldn't assume anyone calling your procedure will have `serveroutput` on, or even be using a client capable of consuming `dbms_output` messages.

Comment: thank you very much for your help this is exactly what i was trying to do